# Does Twilio SMS message log get cleaned up?

Tags: twilio

Twilio has a nice SMS message log resource that I can query via the REST API. Do developers need to write a garbage collection service to delete old SMS messages? Or is there some retention policy?

Otherwise - will I be charged? (I see MMS storage needs to be deleted manaully)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

Twilio will only charge you for storing pictures on the [Media Instance Resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/media#instance). Your SMS messages will stay there, and you can query them via the API whenever.

Your messages also stay for as long as you own the number.